# InfoPath 2013: Customizing "Browse" window of Person\Group Picker

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, people-picker

In Person\Group Picker, I can see 'All Users', 'Active Directory' and 'Organizations' in left section.

[image]

Whenever I search using Person\Group Picker, it shows results from only 'Organizaitons'.

So I want to hide other options and only want to show Organizations in the left section.